# Assign for-loop condition to a variable

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to assign a variable as the conditional operator in a `for` loop in Javascript?

For example, take this `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0, j = 5; i < 10; i++, j++) {
    console.log(i + ", " + j);
}
```

I want to be able to set the `i < 10` part as a variable. I might want the for loop to run until `j < 8` instead of `i < 10`. The way I am currently doing it is using an `if` statement and then using two different `for` loops with the exact same code except for the conditional, and I just wanted to know if a more efficient way was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function in the for loop and reassign it to whatever you want.

```
var predicate = function(i, j) { return i < 10; }

for(var i = 0, j = 5; predicate(i, j); i++, j++) {
    console.log(i + ", " + j);
    if (i === 5) { // Dummy condition
        predicate = function(i, j) { return j < 8; };
    }
}
```

The advantage is that you can completely change the logic if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `10` with a variable. You cannot replace the *operator* (`<`) with a variable.

You can replace the entire expression with a function though, and that function can be stored in a variable.

```
var data = ["a", "b", "c"];

function loop(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; callback(i); i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}

loop(function (i) {
    return (i < 10);
});

loop(function (i) {
    return (i < 8);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, did you try just sticking variables in there :

```
var total = true==true ? 8 : 10,
    i     = 0,
    j     = 5,
    what  = true==false ? i : j;

for(; what < total; i++, j++) {
    console.log(i + ", " + j);
}
```

Comment: I think you need a leading `;`: `for(; what < total; i++, j++)`.

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you can create a random function for this?

```
function countdown = (function(){
   var i =0, j = 5;
   return function(){
       ++i; ++j;
       return i < 10; // or j < 8
   }
})();

while(countdown()) {
    console.log('counting');
}
```

The only problem with that is that you cannot access `i` and `j` in the scope of your loop.